# get current value from datasource loop in a groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui

my problem is, that I have a few teststeps starting with a Datasource Loop with a Grid Datasource, which contains 3 lines (1 line per loop is used) with ${DataSource#columnName} I get the values from the current line during Soapui teststeps to work with them. Is there a way within the groovy script to read the current value?

DataSource:

[image]

Teststeps:

[image]

Here I want to make a DataSource Loop in SoapUI and an Assertion Teststep in a Groovy Script which jumps to a Teststep, depending on which test is right now in the Datasource Loop.

So on 3 DataSource runs it jumps on the first to Teststep xyz and on the other 2 runs it just passes through

I hope this explanation is clear, if not please ask what you need to make my question more clear

best regards

Comment: Actually it is not clear at all. Code snippet would help plus some additional explanation of what data you want to catch in the variable.

Comment: Added some more explanation

Comment: @DominikLemberger, you are saying: "with ${DataSource#columnName} I get the values from the current line... Is there a way within the groovy script to read the current value" - Sounds like you know how to get current value...

Comment: @daggett you can look at the answer that is given now, the ${...} only works within teststeps, but did not work in the script, thats why I wasnt able to manage it, with the context.expand it works now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your not far from getting your value ... anyway ...
to get the value of the current loop, you shall use something like

```
def my_value= context.expand( '${DataSource#my_column}' )
```

to obtain this value, either you set the line above in your script, either (From your example I see that you use ReadyAPI) you right click in your script/ getData / select your Datasource then select the property (column) from which you want to get the value.

This way you can track the value, the id, etc.

If you want to know dynamically which row you are parsing, you can set

```
testRunner.testCase.testSteps['DataSource'].currentRow
```

hope this helps

Alex

Comment: Thanks, the right click GetData really helped, didnt know it / find it.

Comment: you're welcome ... it avoids frustrating mistyping errors  ;)